# How can I auto-play a YouTube playlist using mps-youtube?

Tags: command-line, youtube

I looked into the documentation of [mps-youtube](https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube) but to me it is not clear how to play a YouTube playlist the same way I would play the playlist directly on YouTube.

Let's take the following example playlist:

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFygEs0Hto_pFR897UnySP8QvZdFCNyjX
```

On YouTube, I click on "Play All" to auto-play the entire playlist. After each song, the player automatically jumps to the next song in the playlist.

How can I play a playlist exactly in this way using mps-youtube?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube/pull/594

Comment: @M.Becerra would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @Zanna Sure I would, but the problem is that [the link I shared](https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube/pull/594) isn't exactly what she asked for. She wanted to autoplay a **playlist** and so far I only found how to autoplay **youtube's selection of suggested videos**. So idk whats best to do :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the same behavior in `mpsyt` by first loading the playlist with

```
pl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANEpNH2GiUQ&list=PL3tRBEVW0hiBzIOB97URaYILQdNCMZnvn
```

it will show all videos in the playlist. To play all you can simply type

```
1-
```

which will play all videos from the first. If you want to play shuffled you can type

```
shuffle
```

before starting the playback with the command above.

Comment: Okay, where did you get the `1-` information? I've been reading the documentation and couldn't find it!

Answer (score 1):

You can play playlist directly mpv with this command:

```
mpv https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFygEs0Hto_pFR897UnySP8QvZdFCNyjX
```

It's more efficient as I don't think mpsyt has implemented this function

Answer (score 0):

When opening the example link you [mentioned in the question](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFygEs0Hto_pFR897UnySP8QvZdFCNyjX) you get the following error:

> The playlist does not exist.

using the `dapl` command you can download a different (and valid) [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGwWNGJdvx8&list=PLMC9KNkIncKtGvr2kFRuXBVmBev6cAJ2u)

```
dapl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGwWNGJdvx8&list=PLMC9KNkIncKtGvr2kFRuXBVmBev6cAJ2u
```

More info in the mps help:

```
h download
```

> ```
>  dapl <url or id> - download YouTube playlist (audio) by url or id.
>  dvpl <url or id> - download YouTube playlist (video) by url or id.
> ```

Comment: The playlist was just meant as an example. It doesn't actually exist. I am not sure I understand your `dapl` command as I am referring to mps-youtube here.

Comment: in mps-youtube, executed as `mpsyt` you have access to command line, which allows you to run `h` as `help`, and `dvpl url` allows you to download youtube playlist

Comment: more info in https://github.com/mps-youtube/mps-youtube

Comment: I see, thanks! Please see the comment above by M. Becerra. He already provided the solution.

Comment: `dapl` does not answer the question. I think users expect mps to play while streaming, otherwise we could just `youtube-dl` the playlist and play using mpv.